# Android Studio crash when retrieving content from array

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, android-listview

This might be a simple question, but I just can't figure it out. Consider the code below:

```
private void getJSONData() {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://dev.vision-is.nl/klanten/so/content.json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String titleString = (String) jsonObject.get("title");

                    titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();

                    titleArray.add(titleString);

                    System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(arg1);
        }


    });

}
```

This code works and gives me the output:

```
01-20 13:11:48.076  31508-31508/com.soccer.soccerapp I/System.out﹕ OUTPUT: Barcelona - Real Madrid
01-20 13:11:48.076  31508-31508/com.soccer.soccerapp I/System.out﹕ OUTPUT: Ajax - Barcelona
01-20 13:11:48.077  31508-31508/com.soccer.soccerapp I/System.out﹕ OUTPUT: Manchester United - Chelsea
01-20 13:11:48.078  31508-31508/com.soccer.soccerapp I/System.out﹕ OUTPUT: Ajax - PSV
```

**Here comes the problem!** When I try to retrieve the array in the "onCreate void" the app will crash...

Code:

```
public class ActivitiesViewController extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> titleArray;

  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activitiesviewcontroller);

     getJSONData();

     System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));

  }

}
```

What is wrong with the code? I retrieve the json data. Store this data in an array and when I try to retrieve this data the app will crash.

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: *What is wrong with the code?* - you're wrongfully expecting that the code in `AsyncHttpClient` will run right away, just in time for that list access to succeed. This will not happen.

Comment: your `System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));` may be run before `AsyncHttpClient` complete inside `getJSONData();` method ..

Comment: @Luksprog I store the data in the array right? So why can't I retrieve it? -.- Sorry im just a beginner in Android Development and really want to understand what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: @Vision Your doing nothing wrong ..but your AsynClient is Playing in between with your code...see my Answer for Explanaion

Comment: @BlackTiger I also thought that was the issue, but how can I test it?!

Comment: @Vision follow nitesh's answer i hope you have some idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an AsyncHttpClient the code to execute the network request will not execute parallel to the rest of your code.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
getJSONData();
System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));
```

This way, getJSONData() will execute, as will the System.out.println(). But the println() will (probably) give an IndexOutOfBoundsException since `titleArray` is still empty.

Why is it empty? The `AsyncHttpClient` will load the data in the background, so your ArrayList will get its content in the `onSuccess` of the `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` *after* the request succeeded and not right after you started the task to download your data. Calling `get()` will start a procedure that will not prevent the rest of your code to execute, thus the println is reading an empty array.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://dev.vision-is.nl/klanten/so/content.json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // Process data after request succeeded
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
            // Print error after request failed
        }
    });
```

The pattern of asynchronous methods is the way we prevent our apps from freezing or crashing, which (of course) irritates our users.

You should execute your task and then process all data when`onSuccess` is called by the `AsyncHttpClient` to confirm that the information you asked for was successfully received. Just don't try to access data of which you're not sure you already have.

You might want to take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 2):

Change your `getJSONData()` method like this

```
 private ArrayList<String>() getJSONData() {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://dev.vision-is.nl/klanten/so/content.json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String titleString = (String) jsonObject.get("title");

                    titleArray.add(titleString);

                    System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(arg1);
        }


    });
     return titleArray;
}
```

then your activity oncreate code should be

```
public class ActivitiesViewController extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> titleArray;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.activitiesviewcontroller);

titleArray = getJSONData();

 System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));

 }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try this code I get the following warning: http://cl.ly/image/0t1N3V2s1b3r

Answer (score 1):

Since you using    `AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();.`

So it is Executing the Next Statement in Asyn Manner.

**i.e**:It is Executing the Next statement in Parallel with Previous way

```
 getJSONData();

 System.out.println(titleArray.get(0));
```

Change the `return` of `getJSONData()` to `ArrayList<String>` from `void`

Now if you try to get the value at different position you can find it

Hope this could help ...